# How can I sign up for a Foursquare account using the iOS API?

Tags: iphone, foursquare

I am working completing an app which makes use of the Foursquare API for iPhone. Logging in with a user name and password works fine as does all the authentication processes. However, when users go to "sign up" for a new account they are presented with a blank screen.

There's nothing in my code that is controlling the presentation of this "sign up" window. The authentication process is being invoked from https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate which also looks to be correct.

Is this something I can control or is this a HTML bug?

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the "sign-up" link on the mobile site currently tries to take the user into the iTunes market to download the foursquare app. There currently isn't a mobile web new-user sign-up flow, so for now, I recommend configuring the containing webview to allow the user to jump into the itunes store. For example:

```
if ([request.url.host isEqualToString:@"itms-apps"]) {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:request.url];
}
```

in the [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIWebViewDelegate). We'll update the reference OAuth code accordingly, thanks for bringing this to our attention!